# How to make images stay on one long line?

Tags: html, css, image

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lexy0202/Le3b2/). I'm trying to create a little gallery thing that the user can navigate by moving their mouse.

That fiddle is just a demo of a problem I'm having with the images. Currently, you can see that as the images scroll left, they "pop" onto the end of the line, rather than flow continuously.

If you take off `overflow:hidden` from the CSS, you can see that the images wrap onto multiple lines, and that's what causes them to "pop" onto the end of the line, rather than flow continuously.

How can I force the images to stay on one line, and thus achieve a continuous flow effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```css
#gallery {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/mwLDu/

It's got as much browser compatibility as you could want, too. http://quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html